# Podio - Embed Field - Empty string issue

Tags: podio

Has anyone had any problems saving values to embed fields with the Podio PHP API?

I keep getting the following error, although I know my array has values:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "Invalid value ""
>   (string): must be non empty string" See bold code below for field
>   returning empty.

I have also tried using the associative array, but get the error 'must use embed or url'. http://podio.github.io/podio-php/fields/#linkembed-field

```
$userItem->fields[$field->external_id] = new PodioEmbedItemField();

                    if (is_array($_POST[$embedName])) {
                        $embedArray = array();
                        $embedValues = $_POST[$embedName];

                        if (isset($embedValues) && !empty($embedValues)) {
                            for ($i = 0; $i < count($embedValues); $i++) {
                                $embedObject = PodioEmbed::create(array('url' => **$embedValues[$i]**));
                                array_push($embedArray, $embedObject);
                            }

                            $userItem->fields[$field->external_id]->values = new PodioCollection($embedArray);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK problem is that PodioEmbed object cannot accept array iteration, you have to assign to a variable as string first and then pass into function.

```
$embedString = $embedValues[$i];
$embedObject = PodioEmbed::create(array('url' => $embedString));
```